# How Do I Create a Branch in SVN under GUI

Tags: svn, version-control, branch

I trying to create a branch of an existing trunk for development under the Apache Subversion gui. I fail while

> Trunk > right_click > Branch/tag > select location > finish

throws error saying location already exists.

Comment: share the scrrenshot

Comment: What GUI are you using?

Comment: @alroc - OMFG, it's obvious - TortoiseSVN!!!

Comment: @LazyBadger at the time I posted the question, no GUI was named. As the post stands now, Bartholomew has still hasn't responded - assumptions have been made and the post edited by others.

Comment: @alroc - "Trunk > right_click > Branch/tag > select location > finish" is **definitely** TSVN workstyle (at least for me)

Comment: it is apache subversion that I use.

Answer (score 0):

You **can not** and **must not** select in repository-browser already existing node.

You have to select **only root** (`/branches`) and manually add|change  trailing part of branch-URL

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got it now .
GUI is quite simple

Trunk > right_click > Branch/tag > select location [should type the destination folder name under "copy to url" field]> finish

just ensure that you don't create branch folder manually but rather type it under "copy to URL"

[image: Apache Subversion -Branch Creation-ScreenShot]